# OrderBy In A HasAndBelongsToMany Relation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Hi can I get help from an expert in ActiveRecord?

I am looking for a solution for a HasAndBelongsToMany relation. I currently have the following

```
    [HasAndBelongsToMany(Table = "SupplierRecordUrls",ColumnKey = "SupplierID", ColumnRef = "RecordUrlID", Lazy = true, OrderBy="??")]
    public virtual IList<RecordUrl> RecordUrls
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

How do I order the above relation by a column in "RecordUrl", for example ... "Name Asc". I have tried referencing a column directly in the class RecordUrl but I receive a "cannot find column "xxxxxx" error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: OrderBy takes SQL, not HQL/NHibernate/ActiveRecord. Maybe your specifying a property name instead of a SQL column name?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a [OrderBy in a HABTM relation here](http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?p=6785&sid=7f1f3a2f1340aa4ae5ceb47e6a7a0d7c).

Add Sort to your relation definition, create a Comparer that implements IComparer and that will do the trick.

In your code, that will give somthing like this :

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(Table = "SupplierRecordUrls",ColumnKey = "SupplierID", ColumnRef = "RecordUrlID", Lazy = true, Sort="MyProject.RecordUrlNameComparer, MyProject.RecordUrl")]
public virtual IList<RecordUrl> RecordUrls
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

With :

```
public class RecordUrlNameComparer: IComparer<RecordUrl>
{
    Int32 System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<RecordUrl>.Compare( RecordUrl x, RecordUrl y )
    {
        return new System.Collections.Comparer( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Compare( x.Name, y.Name );
    } 
} // public class RecordUrlNameComparer: IComparer<RecordUrl>
```

I let you read the article :)

**Edit :**

Your error is now : `Could not instantiate comparator class [MyProject.RecordUrl.RecordUrlComparer, MyProject.RecordUrl] for collection MyProject.Supplier.RecordUrls`

What I would do :

- Create the Comparer as an inner class of RecordUrls.
- Change the Sort to : `Sort = "MyProject.Supplier.RecordUrl$RecordUrlComparer, MyProject.Supplier.RecordUrl"`

If it still doesn't work, you still get the "couldn't instantiate" error, try making the Comparer class static. I'm not sure how it is used, but if it's a static call, that may do the trick :)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the responses! I have setup the IComparer as you have instructed, and trying to compare URL's in ascending order for example return new System.Collections.Comparer( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ).Compare( x.Url, y.Url ); I have also added Sort="MyProject.RecordUrlNameComparer, MyProject.RecordUrl" to the HABTM attribute but it seems to ignore the sort parameter any suggestions?

Comment: Sort != OrderBy. Sort happens client-side, OrderBy happens server-side.

Comment: I am not using OrderBy I am using Sort, but I am receiving the following error:   Could not instantiate comparator class [MyProject.RecordUrl.RecordUrlComparer, MyProject.RecordUrl] for collection MyProject.Supplier.RecordUrls - Any ideas ??

Comment: @Sukhbir Saini : Edited my post to help you :)